# If $f$, $h$, $f\circ g$, $g\circ h$ are continuous, when is $g$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f\colon X\to Y$, $g\colon Z\to X,$ and $h\colon W\to Z.$ And suppose $f, h,$ $ f\circ g,$ and $g\circ h$ are continuous. Then $g$ is not necessarily continuous. We could take $f$ and $h$ to be identically 0 and pick $g$ such that $g$ is discontinuous but $g^{-1}(\{0\})\subset Z$ is open.

What conditions would we need to impose so that $g$ is continuous?

Comment: I conjecture. If $h$ is surjective and closed, and the composition with $f$ is continuous then $f$ is continuous. Similarily if $g$ is injective and open ,and the pre-composition is continuous then $f$ is continuous.